# Embed videos that are downloaded in my PC instead of youtube link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use downloaded videos instead of these. But it doesn't work. Any help?

```html
<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <iframe id="myvideo" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lHjyL2MZmGo" style="width: 1280px; height: 720px; border: none;" ></iframe>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <a href="#null" class="videolink" onclick="document.getElementById('myvideo').src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/iwkLMZ2mksw'">Elephant or hathi safari @ chitwan national park, Nepal</a> |
    <a href="#null" class="videolink" onclick="document.getElementById('myvideo').src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/4UffCN6XsrA'">National Parks and Wildlife Reserves of Nepal</a> | 
    <a href="#null" class="videolink" onclick="document.getElementById('myvideo').src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/bU9u-tGL3hY'">Declared an endangered species tiger count begins in Nepal</a> | 
    <a href="#null" class="videolink" onclick="document.getElementById('myvideo').src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/-AXC0SogPN4'">One Horned Rhino- strolling in the streets of Nepal.</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `iframe` is sending you to YouTube's embedded video player, you can't replace the `src` of an `iframe` with a video file.

I would start with the `HTML5` `<video>` element. With that, you should be able to change the `src`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video